# Trouble parsing json/string version of array in Angular controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json

Edited question for better clarity!

I'm building an angular-rails app and am having trouble with parsing an array. One of my ActiveRecord models has an array for an attribute. 
In my rails controller before it hits my angular app, the array looks like this:

```
def show
  @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
# @thing.list => ["{\"content\"=>\"first index\"}", "{\"content\"=>\"second index\"}"]
  render json: @recipe
end

# resulting json for @thing:

{
  id: 1,

  title: "thing",

  list: [
          "first index",
          "second index"
        ],
}
```

And then once inside my angular controller the array attribute looks like:

```
thing.list => ["{"content"=>"one"}", "{"content"=>"two"}"]
```

Of course I need it to look like:

```
[{content: "one"}, {content:"two"}]
```

I've tried JSON.parse on both my Rails and Angular sides of the application but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

> **Parsing JSON**
>
> To parse a JSON string received by another application or generated
>   within your existing application:

```
require 'json'

my_hash = JSON.parse('{"hello": "goodbye"}')
puts my_hash["hello"] => "goodbye"
```

> **Generating JSON**
>
> Creating a JSON string for communication or serialization is just as
>   simple.

```
require 'json'

my_hash = {:hello => "goodbye"}
puts JSON.generate(my_hash) => "{\"hello\":\"goodbye\"}"
```

> Or an alternative way:

```
require 'json'
puts {:hello => "goodbye"}.to_json => "{\"hello\":\"goodbye\"}"
```

[Ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html)

Comment: Belated thanks for your input yesterday. I've edited my question above to make things clearer and add more info, but long story short, I've had no luck using JSON.parse() on the array/json/string/whatever-it-is attribute inside my angular controller. As you can see from my code snippets in my question, the object appears to render proper json just fine on the rails side. I think Ruby and JavaScript must be parsing differently.